# Not able to get the value, getting the position

Tags: r

I am trying to get the first non zero value but I am getting the position using my code. I know I am getting this as I am using which in my code but I need the value. Please help I am sharing my sample data and the R query I used.

```
Cnt<- c(9940000126,9940000188,9940000406,9940000992,9940001017,9940001288,9940001833,9940002276,9940002629)
FY12_April <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
FY12_August <- c(0,0,.343545,0,0,0,0,0,0)
FY12_December <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
FY12_February <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
FY12_January <- c(0,0,0.98557,0,0,0,0,0,0.41949703)
FY12_July <- c(0,0,0,0,0,-1.211583915,0,0,0)
FY12_June <- c(-1.47268885,0,0,0,-0.80164469,0,0,0,0)

SamData <- data.frame(Cnt,FY12_April,FY12_August,FY12_December,FY12_February,FY12_January,FY12_July,FY12_June)

ProcessData <- SamData %>% mutate(Count = apply(select(.,FY12_April:FY12_June),1,function(x) sum(x!=0,na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(FirstInst = colnames(select(.,FY12_April:FY12_June))[apply(select(.,FY12_April:FY12_June),1,function(x)which(x!=0)[1])]) %>%
  mutate(FirstInstAmt = apply(select(.,FY12_April:FY12_June),1,function(x)which(x!=0, arr.ind = TRUE, useNames = TRUE)[1]))
```

[image: Current Output]

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col` with row index to get the value.  It would be more efficient rather than `apply`

```
SamData$FirstInstAmt <- SamData[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(SamData)), 
             max.col(SamData[-1] != 0, 'first'))]
```

---

Or if we want to use `apply`

```
SamData$FirstInstAmt <- apply(SamData[-1], 1, function(x) x[x !=0][1])
SamData$FirstInstAmt
#[1] -1.4726888         NA  0.3435450         NA -0.8016447 
#[6] -1.2115839         NA         NA  0.4194970
```

---

Or using `pmap` with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
SamData %>%
    mutate(FirstInstAmt = pmap_dbl(.[-1], ~  {x <- c(...); x[x != 0][1]}))
```

---

Or use `c_across` with `rowwise`

```
SamData %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(FirstInstAmt = {tmp <- c_across(FY12_April:FY12_June)
                tmp[tmp!= 0][1]})
```

---

Or replace the 0 values with `NA` and use `coalesce` to return the first non-NA

```
SamData %>% 
     mutate(FirstInstAmt  =  coalesce(!!! .[-1] * NA^(!.[-1])))
```

NOTE: Using `rowwise/c_across` or `pmap` or `apply` could be slower as these are loops.  The most efficient among this would be based on indexing (`max.col`) or to a certain extent the `coalesce/replace`